# Create a horizontal menu into a block using megamenu

Tags: magento2, menu

I'm using magento  2.1.6

I need to get default horizontal menu in an CMS block. I have tried to call block this way:

> {block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.topnav"
>   template="Magento_Theme::html/topmenu.phtml" ttl="3600"}}

Its not appearing on frontend and not generate any log.

How can I change megamenu to default Magento categories?

Comment: Try this {{block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="Magento_Theme::html/topmenu.phtml"}}

Comment: You should change the name of the block.